# missing FROM-clause entry for table in posgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am learning db queries and I came across a situation where I have get and field depending on some condition

```
    select brandname 
    from shopping_men_women_fashion.shoppingbrandmaster 
    where shoppingbrandmaster.brandid =clothing.brandid
```

It is throwing an error

```
 missing FROM-clause entry for table clothing.brandid
```

What is this error about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to join `clothing Table`

```
SELECT shoppingbrandmaster.brandname
FROM   shopping_men_women_fashion.shoppingbrandmaster,
       clothing
WHERE  shoppingbrandmaster.brandid = clothing.brandid
```

OR

```
SELECT shoppingbrandmaster.brandname
FROM   shopping_men_women_fashion.shoppingbrandmaster
       JOIN clothing
         ON shoppingbrandmaster.brandid = clothing.brandid
```

Comment: one small mistake from my side, it has to be Select shoppingbrandmaster.brandname or clothing.brandname instead of Select brandname......
otherwise it will give as ambiguous reference

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your syntax with table aliases and [`USING`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM):

```
SELECT s.brandname
FROM   shopping_men_women_fashion.shoppingbrandmaster s
JOIN   shopping_men_women_fashion.clothing            c USING (brandid);
```

I assume your second table also lives in the schema `shopping_men_women_fashion`. If it makes sense to schema-qualify one table, it makes sense to schema-qualify the other.

(The column alias `c` for `clothing` isn't referenced in this example and can be removed.)